# How to compile for 32 bit?

Tags: c, eclipse

Compile dll in eclipse using minGW, dll turns 64, and I need to 32.
Tried to change the settings: C/C++ Build - GCC C++ Compiler - Command - g++ -m32. But it does not help.

What settings should I change?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the 64 bit install of the MinGW compiles only for 64 bit (i.e. 64 bit targeted binaries) and vice versa a 32 bit install of MinGW compiles only for 32 bit. It appears that you have installed a 64 bit version of the MinGW. To create a 32 bit binary you would need to install a 32 bit version of the MinGW.